# Cannot open File protocol links in Resource protocol page in Firefox 41

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've made a local file (log.html) in Firefox profile and tried to open it in an add-on page (add-on folder/data/log.html and it's shown as Resource protocol in URL bar).

```
self.port && self.port.on('add-log-path', function(payLoad) {
  addLogPath(payLoad);
});

function addLogPath(url) {
    // url == "file:///Users/usr/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/05rhodfg.cfxo/log.html"
    $('#logpath').attr('href', url);
}
```

I've also tried changing that to JS method window.open

```
function addLogPath(url) {
    $('#logpath').on("click", function() {
        window.open(url);
    });
}
```

But the error is

> JavaScript error: , line 0: Error: Access to
>   'file:///Users/usr/Library/Application%20Support/Firefox/Profiles/05rhodfg.cfxo/log.html'
>   from script denied

BTW, before Firefox version 41, it has no problem doing this.
Can you suggest other workaround to solve this? Thank you!

edit: 
[added add-on example to reproduce the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iijff8a5vo5guq7/fileProtocolExample.zip?dl=0)

download and run the following statement in Terminal:
$ cd fileProtocolExample && cfx run

Answer (score 0):

Do `self.data.url('filename_here')` to get that path to your file.

It will look something like `resource://your-extension-id/data/filename_here`, then this should load fine. That `resource://` in front is important, make sure you get and use that URL.

The `file://` won't work, because your addon is packed in a zip. Its not extracted into the system. How did it work in Firefox 41? Was your addon unpacked at that time? This is an Addon-SDK addon right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's an addon-sdk addon. The URL linking to the log file is fine (and it's starting with file:/// and I can copy and paste the URL to open the local file in a new tab in Firefox). And the addon writes / updates the log file to local Firefox profile instead of reading from XPI package. I will try to make a minimized version of the addon that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added the example file. Please check if you have time :)

Comment: @ZER0 ZER0 would you please help me on this one?